# make the variable thread safe

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

```
Public void example(int a,int b)
{
   int d=a;
   int w, c;
   ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out w, out c);
   ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, c);  
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(method), d);                    
}

Public void method(object d)
{
   console.Writeline(d);
}
```

Problem: when a thread enters example(), it comes its own value of a which is assigned to c. By the time that thread comes to the statement `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(method), d)`  ,           a new thread enters example(), and modifies the value of c. And hence first thread also sends the modified value of d to `method()`. As a result both the threads print the same value of `d`.

Requirement: I want each each thread to hold the its own value of d, the second thread which enters  `method()`should not modifty the first thread value of d. I know 'lock(obj)' can be an option. Sugget me some good ways of locking in this scenario and other ways by which I can achieve me requirement. 
Note: Consider the thread flow to be high.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Ever call to method will have the value of c that was present at the time of its `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`. They won't share a "single" value of c.

Comment: @HansPassant This won't even compile. two local variables named `c` :(

Comment: This question still makes no sense to me. Write up a small program that compiles, runs, and demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As I've told you, what you said is false. Each `method` will use the value it received. A little test (I've modified your code so that the threads will start at the same time)

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    static void example(int a, int b)
    {
        int d = a;
        int w, c;
        ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out w, out c);
        ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, c);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(method), d);
    }

    static void method(object d)
    {
        mre.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine(d);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        example(1, 2);
        example(3, 4);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("The threads are still waiting after 1 sec...");
        mre.Set();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Now I hope they finished");
    }
}
```